# Check unity in a regression

Tags: statistics, regression, roots-of-unity, linear-regression, mean-square-error

I have the following question:

[image]

The equation from part c:

[image]

## My Solution

I'm thinking of solving this problem using the RESET test so something along the lines of:

$$yl_t = -0.027 + 0.537 kl_t + \hat{y}_t^2o$$

where $o$ is the coefficient.

That being said I know this is wrong, I have absolutely no idea on how to approach this problem.

Comment: It is needed point (c).

Comment: @Nicg Thank you very much for your answer. very sorry for this, I completely forgot to add it. I just updated my question.

Comment: Ok now makes sense: do you have familiarity with T and F Tests?

Comment: @Nicg Yes, I'm familiar with both tests

Comment: Great! So, at me it seems you need a T - test for $\hat{\beta_{l}}$ $+$ $\hat{\beta_{k}}$ $=$ 1. Although the fact that it instead gives you the values for the F test leaves me a bit puzzled.

Comment: @Nicg Thanks for your reply once again, I can upload the whole pdf if it will help. I've spend almost all day trying to figure it all out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I see. So, in point (c), you have:

$$log(y) = \beta_{0} + \beta_{k}log(k) + \beta_{l}log(l) + \varepsilon$$

and estimate it: we will call this the $unrestricted$ model, since we aren't making any restriction on the parameters. We find that $SSE_{unrest}$ $=$ $0.085$

Let's now move to the $restricted$ model. In Economic terms, you are assuming constant returns to scale: have $\beta_{k}$ $+$ $\beta_{l}$ $=$ $1$. Working out the algebra we obtain the model you have in point (e):

$$log(\frac{y}{l}) = \beta_{0} + \beta_{kl}log(\frac{k}{l})$$.

We know that, for this model, $SSE_{rest}$ $=$ $0.115$. Considering that we have, de facto, put one only restriction, the F Test will be:

$$F = \frac{\frac{SSE_{rest} - SSE_{unrest}}{1}}{\frac{SSE_{unrest}}{n - k}} = \frac{0.115 - 0.085}{\frac{0.085}{n - 3}}$$

where $n$ is the sample size. You then have to check whether the computed F is larger or not of $F_{1, n - 3}$. If yes, Reject the hypothesis $\beta_{k}$ $+$ $\beta_{l}$ $=$ $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, why is $_k + _l = 1$?

Comment: Because that's the hypothesis that is required to be tested by point (e), your actual question.